# What nameserver to use when buying .to domain?

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

They want me to put primary and secondary nameserver?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either:

- Set-up your own nameservers (I guess from your question that's not what you want)
- Use nameservers provided by your registrar (I guess from your question that your registrar does not provide nameservers)
- Use nameservers provided by your webhosting (most webhostings do)
- Subscribe to any 3-rd party DNS hosting, see [this list](http://talkdns.info/list)